# Ordering headers in http requests JAVA

Tags: java, python-requests, okhttp

So I'm on this situation where I have to make requests to an API but the headers should follow a specific order or the request will be dropped by the server (I'm sure the headers order causing it).
I already tried HttpUrlConnection and OkHttp3 but couldn't make the headers be ordered how I want them to be.
I'm not limited to HttpUrlConnection and OkHttp3 only I can use any library if it will solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The HTTP specification ([RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html)) explicitly states that *"the **order** in which header fields with differing field names are received is **not significant**"*. --- [RFC7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2) says the same thing. --- If a server requires a certain order, then the server is broken and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp will add additional headers on your behalf: Content-Length, Transfer-Encoding, User-Agent, and others. If you want to reorder these headers you have to do it in a network Interceptor. Probably the best strategy is to write a network Interceptor that replaces the incoming request’s Headers object with a new instance you construct that meets the ordering requirements.